# Using Regex on a variable in a SQL function

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, replace

I'm working on a SQL developer function that standardizes street suffixes in a table of addresses. Originally I had a series of replace statements with regex like this:

```
select replace (ADDRESS, '(^|\s)(AVENUE)($|\s)', ' AVE ') into ADDRESS from dual;
```

But to try to decrease the length of the function, I changed it to a cursor which looks like this:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR CHANGE_SUFFIX
       IS
          SELECT *
            FROM SUFFIX_LIST;
    BEGIN
       FOR SUFFIX_LIST
       IN CHANGE_SUFFIX
       LOOP
            select regexp_replace (ADDRESS, SUFFIX_LIST.ORIG_SUFFIX, SUFFIX_LIST.CHANGED_SUFFIX) into ADDRESS from dual;
       END LOOP;
END;
```

Where I have a table (SUFFIX_LIST) with a column of what should be changed (ORIG_SUFFIX) and what it's supposed to change into (CHANGED_SUFFIX).

The issue I'm having is that I can't find a way to apply the original regex to the replace statement in the cursor. I tried including it like

```
 select regexp_replace (ADDRESS, (^|\s)SUFFIX_LIST.ORIG_SUFFIX($|\s), SUFFIX_LIST.CHANGED_SUFFIX) into ADDRESS from dual
```

But that gives an error (missing expression) and putting it in single quotes treats it like a string. Any help appreciated, please lmk if there are any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the anchors to be strings, but then you need to concatenate them with the table values:

```
        select regexp_replace (ADDRESS, '(^|\s)' || SUFFIX_LIST.ORIG_SUFFIX || '($|\s)',
            SUFFIX_LIST.CHANGED_SUFFIX) into ADDRESS from dual;
```

Or you could do that concatenation in the cursor query. As `ADDRESS` is a PL/SQL variable you also don't need to select from dual to modify that; you can just assign it:

```
        address := regexp_replace (ADDRESS, '(^|\s)' || SUFFIX_LIST.ORIG_SUFFIX || '($|\s)',
            SUFFIX_LIST.CHANGED_SUFFIX);
```

You can do the same concatenation to add the spaces back around the `CHANGED_SUFFIX` values if the table values don't have those. (Presumably you trim them off at the end...)

Comment: Thanks, the concatenate was exactly what I was looking for. Not sure why but when I tried to concatenate a space to the end of changed suffix, I got an error "character string buffer too small" even though I'm pretty sure my varchar2 was set with enough memory for the string. However I was able to edit the table to add a trailing space and it worked.